# optimize/minimize linear function where each variable has "steps" that can be upgraded

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

I have used sklearn's linear regression function in Python to come up with a surrogate model to describe energy use (in GJ) of a residential house. The parameters are:

- Air changes per hour
- Wall Insulation R-Value
- Roof Insulation R-Value
- Slab Insulation R-Value
- Basement Wall Insulation R-Value
- Furnace Efficiency
- Window U-Value
- HRV Efficiency

For each of these parameters there is a baseline value, and I have 3 "levels" of retrofit upgrades that could be performed, and the associated cost. For example, the baseline furnace efficiency is 80%. The Level 1 upgrade is 5,000 dollars to get to 90% efficiency, Level 2 is 8,000 for 95% efficiency, and Level 3 is 12,000 for 98% efficiency.

I would like to optimize the best order to perform these upgrades to minimize **cost per GJ saved** (compared to the baseline). Each parameter can only be upgraded one level per step. For example, the answer could be:

- Step 1: upgrade furnace to level 1
- Step 2: upgrade furnace to level 2
- Step 3: increase wall insulation to level 1
- Step 4: upgrade furnace to level 3
- Step 5: upgrade window to level 1
- Step 6: increase wall insulation to level 2
- etc..

I know that this could be done using brute force however I was looking for a better solution if possible. I'm wondering how I could go about setting this up. What would it be called and how could I find more info? Or, does anybody see an easier way to do this and get the same result? Any help would be much appreciated.

I was looking into linear programming but my constraints aren't inequalities? Not sure if they could be converted to them, or if thats the wrong direction for a problem like this.

Thanks!

Comment: p.s. sorry for the title... i was not sure how to describe the question